# List of all Resources in my Azure Subscription + IAM Access Control Credentials

Tags: azure, powershell, command, azure-active-directory

I need to export all the Resources from my Azure subscription and i got the command for this:

**Get-AzureRmResource | Export-CSV C:\temp\azure-resources.csv**

But I want to export all IAM Access Control Information from each Resource separately, to see all the user that has access to this resource and all the permissions.

Does someone have an idea how to do it with PS commands?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try the command below to export the each resource IAM information(role assignment) to CSV.

```
$resource = (Get-AzureRmResource | Select-Object ResourceId).ResourceId 

foreach($item in $resource){
    $role += Get-AzureRmRoleAssignment -Scope $item 
}

$role | Export-CSV C:\Users\joyw\Desktop\test.csv
```

[image]

Comment: Yes that almost what I need but I need to know what resource is Associated to the Display names because I don't see here any of the Resource Name like Key Vault and others.

Comment: @alex The display name should be in the `Scope`, but due to your user is in the IAM of the subscription, so the `Scope` will be like `/subscriptions/xxxxxx`, if your user is just in the IAM of the specific resource(e.g. keyvault) not the whole subscription, it will be like `/subscriptions/xxxxx/resourceGroups/xxxx/providers/Microsoft.KeyVault/vaults/keyvaultname`. If the user is under the subscription, he will be access to all the resources of the subscription. Sample: https://i.stack.imgur.com/9Ixp8.png

Comment: Ok, I see, but if I want to see all the resource names exactly how in Azure? for example, AlexKeyVault and type will be Key Vault.

Comment: @alex If so, you need to split the output manually, this is a bit complicated. I think my reply is helpful enough to be marked as the answer.

Comment: Thanks Joy for your help